# Нужно переписать код по образцу

Tags: reactjs

Есть условие для setState

```js
if (containerWidth <= 719) {
      this.setState({
        displayed: 1
      });
    }
else {
      this.setState({
        displayed: 3
      });
    }
```

нужно записать его в такой форме

```
condition ? value_if_condition_true : value_if_condition_false;
```

должно быть что то типа этого

```
this.setState({isMobile: containerWidth <= 700});
```

просто в этом примере, в отличие от вопроса, состояние isMobile может быть true или false, а в вопросе в состоянии число

Answer (score 2):

```js
this.setState({
  displayed: containerWidth <= 719 ? 1 : 3
});
```